# What is the best Rifle/SubMachine Gun in Metal Gear Solid 4?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-4-guns-of-patriots

What is the best Rifle and submachine gun in Metal Gear Solid 4? By best I mean, best rate of fire and greatest damage.

Comment: I would probably argue that this question is heavily opinion based. Obviously a rocket launcher or shotgun would be among the weapons that have the highest damage assuming you hit all your pellets. Damage is also very subjective. Are you looking for highest single bullet damage or highest DPS in general? If you want to compare them you can take a look at the wiki https://metalgear.fandom.com/wiki/Metal_Gear_Solid_V:_The_Phantom_Pain_weapons_and_equipment#AIR-S%20%E2%98%86%208

Answer (score 3):

I'm a big fan of the MP7. The high rate of fire, low recoil, and good power for a little gun make it a good stopper, and being able to fit it with a scope when needed holds it above the P90. I would have loved to see the 40-round mag in this game, though, because you can burn through the little 20-rounders quick if you aren't careful. If I'm trying to stay quiet, I'll stick with the MP5SD2.

On the rifle side of things, I tend to use the M14EBR quite a bit, probably one of the best all-rounders in the game. Controllable on auto with bursts, can be fitted with a suppressor, common ammunition, two-stage scope, and 20 rounds of 7.62x51. I would like it better if you could pop corners with it, though.

Answer (score 1):

These are my personal preferences ... I think they are the best!

Best Submachine gun: 
Bizon :  Its magazine holds sixty-four 9mm x 18 rounds. Has only moderate stopping power, but its large magazine capacity cuts down on reloads.

Best Assualt Rifle: 
FAL Carbine: It fires the 7.62x51mm round and has a 20 round magazine.